# Spring Boot WebSocket with embedded ActiveMQ Broker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-websocket

I tried to change an web application from simple broker to an embedded ActiveMq Broker with stomp using Spring boot 1.5.4 but always getting an error on start up

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No handlers
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.start(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:244) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

I reduced the failure with an simple example

**POM File ***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>websocket</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-stomp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-net</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Application Class**

```
package com.example.websocket;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebsocketApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebsocketApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**WebSocketConfig Class**

```
package com.example.websocket;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableJms
public class WebSocketConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport {

    @Value("${spring.activemq.user}")
    private String mqUser;
    @Value("${spring.activemq.password}")
    private String mqPasword;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic") //
        .setRelayHost("localhost") //
        .setRelayPort(61613) //
        .setClientLogin(mqUser) //
        .setClientPasscode(mqPasword) //
        ;
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  activemq:
    broker-url: stomp://localhost:61613
    user: user
    password: pass
```

Someone knows my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My problem was the EnableWebSocketMessageBroker Annotation and missing deployment of ActiveMQ Broker

Remove the application.yml and change WebSocketConfig class to

```
package com.example.websocket;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport {


    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic") //
        .setRelayHost("localhost") //
        .setRelayPort(61613);
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
        final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.addConnector("stomp://localhost:61613");

        broker.setPersistent(false);
        final ManagementContext managementContext = new ManagementContext();
        managementContext.setCreateConnector(true);
        broker.setManagementContext(managementContext);

        return broker;
    }
}
```

works for me.

Comment: I tried so many ways and yours too but I am getting error
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.messageBrokerTaskScheduler()'
I am using spring boot 2.1.8