# How can configure activemq ex. queue time to live , or keep the message in queue until period of time or action?

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, stomp, spring-websocket, server-push

I am building notification system using **spring boot** and **websocket**, I used **ActiveMQ** to keep Queues for offlines users, it's working perfect.

I need to edit some configuration like queue time to live, keep message in queue until user read it, I don't know how can configure it?

The below is its implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker 
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

      @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
            /*config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
            config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");*/

          config
            .setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
            .setUserDestinationPrefix("/user")
            .enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic","/queue","/user")

            .setRelayHost("localhost")
            .setRelayPort(61613)
            .setClientLogin("guest")
            .setClientPasscode("guest");


        }


        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").withSockJS();
        }

}
```

And:

```
@Service
public  class NotificationWebSocketService {
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

public void initiateNotification(WebSocketNotification notificationData) throws InterruptedException {

messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(notificationData.getUserID(), "/reply", notificationData.getMessage());

}
}
```

After invoke NotificationWebSocketService it will create queue "/user/Johon/reply" in activemq contains message when user subscribe in this queue message will received.

How can configure  queue time to live , keep message in queue until user read it?

Comment: good luck to you @userdemo

Comment: "keep message in queue until user read it" this is the principle of a queue. unless you use a topic and in this case you need to use a queue...

Comment: @HassenBennour yes i do it , when user subscribe `stompClient.subscribe('/user/Johon/reply', function (greeting) {
            showGreeting(greeting.body);
        });`  the messages received  , but myconcern how to control time to live for queue '/user/Johon/reply' , and if there are away to keep this messages

Comment: "stompClient.subscribe('/user/Johon/reply'' -->  '/user/Johon/reply'  is a topic and not a queue. this is the reason why i do not understood your concern.

Comment: You can set "expires" header ( in milliseconds ) and use convertAndSendToUser version with headers support.

Comment: @user1516873 yes it's working ,there are a way to keep messages in queue at least 10 messages , and determine which messages read or not as flag in activemq as mention above it's notification module user login multiple times i need keep for example last 10 messages

Answer (score 0):

"stompClient.subscribe('/user/Johon/reply' --> '/user/Johon/reply' is a topic and not a queue.

If your Stomp client is not connected to the topic '/user/Johon/reply' he will loose every message sent to that topic.

So your solutions are :

1. convert your topic '/user/Johon/reply' to a queue, so the message remains on the queue indefinitely or until the server end-processes the message.
2. use Retroactive Consumer & Subscription Recovery Policy

> A retroactive consumer is just a regular JMS Topic consumer who
>   indicates that at the start of a subscription every attempt should be
>   used to go back in time and send any old messages (or the last message
>   sent on that topic) that the consumer may have missed.
>   http://activemq.apache.org/retroactive-consumer.html
>
> The subscription recovery policy allows you to go back in time when
>   you subscribe to a topic.
>   http://activemq.apache.org/subscription-recovery-policy.html

3. Use Durable Subscribers

> Durable topic subscribers that are offline for a long period of time
>   are usually not desired in the system. The reason for that is that
>   broker needs to keep all the messages sent to those topics for the
>   said subscribers. And this message piling can over time exhaust broker
>   store limits for example and lead to the overall slowdown of the
>   system.
>   http://activemq.apache.org/manage-durable-subscribers.html

Durable Subscribers with Stomp : 
http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html#Stomp-ActiveMQExtensionstoSTOMP

> CONNECT client-id string Specifies the JMS clientID which is used in
>   combination with the activemq.subcriptionName to denote a durable
>   subscriber.

some explanations about TTL

> A client can specify a time-to-live value in milliseconds for each
>   message it sends. This value defines a message expiration time that is
>   the sum of the message's time-to-live and the GMT when it is sent (for
>   transacted sends, this is the time the client sends the message, not
>   the time the transaction is committed).
>
> the default time to live is 0, so the message remains on the queue
>   indefinitely or until the server end-processes the message

**UPDATE**

if you want to use external ActiveMQ Broker

remove `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` and add to your activemq.xml below connector and restart the broker.

```
 <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61613"/>
```

if you want to embedd ActiveMQ Broker, add bean to you WebSocketConfig :

```
 @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
        final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.addConnector("stomp://localhost:61613");    
        return broker;
    }
```

and required dependencies

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-stomp</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
> ```

full examples 
[Spring Boot WebSocket with embedded ActiveMQ Broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884520/spring-boot-websocket-with-embedded-activemq-broker)

http://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-websocket-integration-example

Comment: Hello Hessen , thank you for your ansewer , but there are some thing strange , when connect into websocket `function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/user/Johon/reply', function (greeting) {
            showGreeting(greeting.body);
        });
    });
} `

Comment: Please see the screenshot (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HOuCoovi3wcXSRrFvdiBJ0lGSHr54uks/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: seconde screenshot (https://drive.google.com/file/d/15nPOfogXu61O-8dA_EmY0OUbUBUHoms9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: i am looking for simple implementation to use **activemq** , please your advice @Hassen Bennour

Comment: see my update. as i see from your jmx screenshot that /user/Johon/reply is a queue, so what is strange ?? have you sent messages to this queue ?

Comment: @Hassan the **queue** not support multi session ? let's say i subscribe from two different browser the same user **/user/User1/reply** first message received first browser the second not , send again first not  second revived  how can solve this ? and if i changed this to topic the topic only for connected user other tahn will lose these message  how can keep these messages give me example ?

Comment: @userdemo any queue deliver a message to one consumer even if there is multiple consumers. so try my solutions 2 and 3

Comment: i changed to topic also try use **Durable Subscribers** but give me error **javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: localhost - Client: my-client-id already connected from** please look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858220/spring-boot-activemq-durable-subscribers

Answer (score 0):

Unit-test to illustrate how to set up expiration of message in user queue.
Required tomcat-embedded, spring-messaging, and active-mq

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.Wrapper;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.ApplicationListener;
import org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsContextListener;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.ChannelRegistration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.*;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptorAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

public class Test48402361 {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test48402361.class);

    private static TomcatWebSocketTestServer server = new TomcatWebSocketTestServer(33333);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        server.deployConfig(Config.class);
        server.start();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() throws Exception {
        server.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUser() throws Exception {

        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(new SockJsClient(Collections.singletonList(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient()))));

        BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        StompSession session = stompClient
                .connect("ws://localhost:" + server.getPort() + "/test", new WebSocketHttpHeaders(), new StompSessionHandlerAdapter() {
                })
                .get();
        // waiting until message 2 expired
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        session.subscribe("/user/john/reply", new StompFrameHandler() {
            @Override
            public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
                return byte[].class;
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                String message = new String((byte[]) payload);
                logger.debug("message: {}, headers: {}", message, headers);
                blockingQueue.add(message);
            }
        });
        String message = blockingQueue.poll(1, SECONDS);
        Assert.assertEquals("1", message);
        message = blockingQueue.poll(1, SECONDS);
        Assert.assertEquals("3", message);

    }

    public static class Config extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] { };
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] { Mvc.class };
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[] { "/" };
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    public static class Mvc extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {

            stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/test")
                    .withSockJS()
                    .setWebSocketEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
            registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/user").setRelayHost("localhost").setRelayPort(61614);
        }

        @Autowired
        private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

        @Override
        public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
            registration.setInterceptors(new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {
                @Override
                public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

                    StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
                    switch (sha.getCommand()) {
                        case CONNECT:
    // after connect we send 3 messages to user john, one will purged after 2 seconds.
                            template.convertAndSendToUser("john", "/reply", "1");
                            Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
                            headers.put("expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000);
                            template.convertAndSendToUser("john", "/reply", "2", headers);
                            template.convertAndSendToUser("john", "/reply", "3");
                            break;
                    }
                    return super.preSend(message, channel);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static class TomcatWebSocketTestServer {

        private static final ApplicationListener WS_APPLICATION_LISTENER =
                new ApplicationListener(WsContextListener.class.getName(), false);

        private final Tomcat tomcatServer;

        private final int port;

        private Context context;


        public TomcatWebSocketTestServer(int port) {

            this.port = port;

            Connector connector = new Connector(Http11NioProtocol.class.getName());
            connector.setPort(this.port);

            File baseDir = createTempDir("tomcat");
            String baseDirPath = baseDir.getAbsolutePath();

            this.tomcatServer = new Tomcat();
            this.tomcatServer.setBaseDir(baseDirPath);
            this.tomcatServer.setPort(this.port);
            this.tomcatServer.getService().addConnector(connector);
            this.tomcatServer.setConnector(connector);
        }

        private File createTempDir(String prefix) {
            try {
                File tempFolder = File.createTempFile(prefix + '.', "." + getPort());
                tempFolder.delete();
                tempFolder.mkdir();
                tempFolder.deleteOnExit();
                return tempFolder;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create temp directory", ex);
            }
        }

        public int getPort() {
            return this.port;
        }


        @SafeVarargs
        public final void deployConfig(Class<? extends WebApplicationInitializer>... initializers) {

            this.context = this.tomcatServer.addContext("", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

            // Add Tomcat's DefaultServlet
            Wrapper defaultServlet = this.context.createWrapper();
            defaultServlet.setName("default");
            defaultServlet.setServletClass("org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet");
            this.context.addChild(defaultServlet);

            // Ensure WebSocket support
            this.context.addApplicationListener(WS_APPLICATION_LISTENER);

            this.context.addServletContainerInitializer(
                    new SpringServletContainerInitializer(), new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(initializers)));
        }

        public void start() throws Exception {
            this.tomcatServer.start();
        }

        public void stop() throws Exception {
            this.tomcatServer.stop();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i used part `Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000);
template.convertAndSendToUser("john", "/reply", "2", headers)`
it's working perfect after 2 second the message will be deleted ,
i have another question , as i mention above i building **notification module**
for ex. when user "john" login he will subscribe '/user/Johon/reply'  all messages in queue ,  there are a way to keep messages in queue at least 10 mesages and if there are any new mesages flag 
to determine new messages and old messages

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your requirements. You want to have some historical data? - so save readed messages in database, queues are for fast async guarantiered delivery, and don't have a API to change message status and mark it as read. When you read it and acknowledge, it is gone.